# Subset dataframe row returned as list?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I want to create a string vector out of a row of a data frame. without its row and column names. This is my dataframe.

```
agreement = c("Strongly Disagree"," Disagree", "Neither", "Agree", "Strongly Agree")
likelihood = c("Very unlikely","Unlikely", "Neither", "Likely", "Very Likely")
df <- as.data.frame(rbind(agreement, likelihood))
```

Once I have the data frame, how do I go back to the character vector without its column values? E.g.

```
> "Strongly Disagree"," Disagree", "Neither", "Agree", "Strongly Agree"
```

I tried with `as.character`, but what I get in return are numeric values.

```
as.character(df[1,1:5])
> "1" "1" "1" "1" "1"
```

I also tried with `as.vector`, but it returns me a list including column names.

```
as.vector(df[1,1:5])
>                        V1        V2      V3    V4             V5
agreement Strongly Disagree  Disagree Neither Agree Strongly Agree
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Or you can also: `as.vector(t(df[1, ]))`

Comment: maybe `sapply(df[1, ],unlist)`. Returns a matrix for multiple rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `stringsAsFactors` to `FALSE` when creating a dataframe.

```
df <- as.data.frame(rbind(agreement, likelihood), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

`as.character(df[1,1:5])` now results in

```
"Strongly Disagree" " Disagree" "Neither" "Agree" "Strongly Agree"
```

When retrieving all rows or columns you can simply leave the field empty e.g (`df[1,]` returns the first row with all columns)

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply! Including `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` returns the same as `as.vector` command above including the column names, how can I return it without the column names?

Comment: To retrieve the result as a vector (in this case character vector) you can assign it to a new value. Using `firstrow <- as.character(df[1,])` will give the desired results. (firstrow is now the same as agreement)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @YusufSyakur's answer for the `as.character` part, you should know a subset of a data.frame with more than one column is always data.frame itself.  Even if there's only one row. And a data.frame is just a list with extra sugar on top, so `as.vector` removes that sugar and leaves the list.

Comment: More a comment than an answer.

Comment: He asked two questions, really: "Why am I getting numbers with `as.character`?" and "Why am I getting a list with `as.vector`?"

Answer (score 0):

Have in mind that you can use tibbles instead of dataframes (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/vignettes/tibble.html)

with a tibble stings are not converted to factors by default. So in your case you could use:

```
df <- as.tibble(rbind(agreement, likelihood))

    > as.character(df[1,1:5])
[1] "Strongly Disagree" " Disagree"         "Neither"           "Agree"             "Strongly Agree"
```